# I want to use office 365 Api for my Asp.net with C# non mvc Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, office365api

Hello Folks I am new to using `API` into my project. 
I am using Asp.Net with `C#` which does not have `MVC architecture`. 
My client needed to integrate office 365 API into the project so that any user who want to access our service can login through their office 365 credentials. 
while I searched on internet about the sources it said I needed ASP.net with `MVC` to use `office 365` . Please suggest what could be done.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Active Directory Authentication Library .NET to easily authenticate users to cloud or on-premises Active Directory (AD), and then obtain access tokens for securing API calls . In web form , code below is for your reference :

```
        protected  void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        string authCode = Request.Params["code"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authCode))
        {
             Authorize(authCode);
        }

        string token = (string)Session["access_token"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            // get user name
            getUserName(token);
        }
        catch (AdalException ex)
        {

        }
    }

    public void getUserName(string token)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //Enable signon and read users' profile
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me"))
            {
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata.metadata=minimal");
                using (var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result)
                {
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        var json = JObject.Parse(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                        Response.Write(json["displayName"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Authorize(string authCode) {
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common");

        // The same url we specified in the auth code request
        string redirectUri = "http://localhost:55065/Default.aspx";

        // Use client ID and secret to establish app identity
        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientID"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"]);

        try
        {
            // Get the token
            var authResult =  authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                authCode, new Uri(redirectUri), credential, "https://graph.microsoft.com/");

            // Save the token in the session
            Session["access_token"] = authResult.AccessToken;


            Response.Redirect(redirectUri.ToString());
        }
        catch (AdalException ex)
        {
            //return Content(string.Format("ERROR retrieving token: {0}", ex.Message));
        }
    }
    public void signin()
    {
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common");


        // The url in our app that Azure should redirect to after successful signin 
        string redirectUri = "http://localhost:55065/Default.aspx";


        // Generate the parameterized URL for Azure signin 
        Uri authUri = authContext.GetAuthorizationRequestURL("https://graph.microsoft.com/", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientID"],
            new Uri(redirectUri), UserIdentifier.AnyUser, null);

        // Redirect the browser to the Azure signin page 
        Response.Redirect(authUri.ToString());
    }
```

You could also refer to below link to get some examples with O365 API in GitHub :
https://github.com/dream-365/OfficeDev-Samples/tree/master/samples/Office365DevQuickStart

But I would suggest you could try to use ASP.NET MVC , it is designed with separation of concerns and testability in mind , and you will find a lot of MVC samples with O365 in here:
[Office 365 API code samples and videos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/HowTo/starter-projects-and-code-samples#bk_web)